# What is get(b:, ...) in VimL?

Tags: vim

The [vim-commentary plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/blob/master/plugin/commentary.vim) for Vim has the following snippet:

```
function! s:surroundings() abort
  return split(get(b:, 'commentary_format', substitute(substitute(substitute(
        \ &commentstring, '^$', '%s', ''), '\S\zs%s',' %s', '') ,'%s\ze\S', '%s ', '')), '%s', 1)
endfunction
```

What does the `b:` mean in the first parameter of `get`? It doesn't seem to match any of the uses of `get`:

> get({list}, {idx} [, {default}])                        *get()*
>                   Get item {idx} from |List| {list}.  When this item is not
>                   available return {default}.  Return zero when {default} is
>                   omitted.
>
> get({dict}, {key} [, {default}])
>                   Get item with key {key} from |Dictionary| {dict}.  When this
>                   item is not available return {default}.  Return zero when
>                   {default} is omitted.
>
> get({func}, {what})
>                   Get an item with from Funcref {func}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to be aware of `b:` as a prefix - an internal namespace (`:help b:`). For example, `b:commentary_format` would be a variable local to the current buffer. But also, as explained in `:help internal-variables`:

> The scope name by itself can be used as a Dictionary.

and you can test that `b:` is a dictionary with `:echo b:`.

Thus, `b:foo` is equivalent to `b:["foo"]`. However, there's no way to specify a default this way. So Mr Pope uses the second form of `get` ("Get item with key `key` from Dictionary `dict`. When this item is not available return `default`") to provide an alternative in case `b:commentary_format` is not defined.

Comment: Learned something. Thanks. This is a "cool" usage of Vim script function, but I would have preferred a clean `if exists("b:commentary_format") ... else ... endif`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's `b:commentary_format`, i.e. a [buffer-local variable](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#buffer-variable)